# Calling A COM Component From .NET Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows, com, service

I have a Windows Service written in .NET C# which calls a COM component. I also have a .NET Windows Forms test app which I was using to test the COM component. It works fine from the test app. However, when I use the same code in the Windows Service nothing happens. The COM components logs everything to file and the fact the log file doesn't get produced hints that the COM component isn't even being called.

Why does this work from my test app but not within the windows service?

Comment: Please give some detail about the COM component. What is it written in, for instance. Maybe the component assumes it is running in a process that has a message pump.

Comment: The component is written in ATL with Visual Studio 6. It is an exe component (not dll or service)

Comment: so, is this the first time you've tried to use the component outside of a desktop application? Never used it in ASP.NET or a web service? That suggests you have a dependency on a message pump or something else that doesn't exist outside of a desktop application.

Comment: Yes this is the first time I've tried to use outside anything other than a desktop application. I'm thinking there is some sort of permissions problem which I am trying to narrow down. Right now I want to narrow down whether the method gets called at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service typically run isolated from the desktop, and therefore your call to the COM component is insulated from the UI when called from the service. You may [allow a service to "interactWithDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502.aspx)"  see the section on **Using an Interactive Service**.

Microsoft (`<sarcasm>in their infinite wisdom</sarcasm>`) Decided that this capability would be removed from Window vista and recommend [separating your application into multiple parts and using other mechanisms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e50d8819-d628-48e2-aa2c-6ac6de8380d9/) to accomplish communication between your UI and your service. Obviously, some (including myself) don't agree, but, it is what it is...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e50d8819-d628-48e2-aa2c-6ac6de8380d9/

Comment: How does that relate to being able to call a COM component from a .NET service?

Comment: I suspect that the service **IS** communicating with COM, but you are not observing that interaction because COM (operating in the service space) can not interact with your desktop (or other user space) to allow you to see that the component is working.

Comment: Why is it if I debug the com component, when I call it from the windows forms app written in C# .NET it will break on the breakpoint at the start of the method but when it is called from the windows service it does not break? This is why I don't think it is calling the COM component.

Comment: Are you just attempting to run the service from VS or are you attaching to the process?  Debugging a service is a little bit different from debugging a Winforms app.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not trying to debug the service. I am debugging the com component being called from the windows service. I can debug the windows service just fine by attaching to the running instance of it. But that is not what I am looking to do currently. I can see that the service is attempting to call the COM component but it doesn't call it. The same code works fine from a forms app.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point in the service before it references the COM component and monitoring the Processes tab of the Task Manager?
Maybe try stepping into the COM component from the Service during a debug (I'm not sure that will work...) 
What version of VS are you using? What OS? Where is the COM component attempting to Log to?

Comment: When the service creates an instance of the com component, I can see that the exe of the com component is loaded in the processes list. The next line which calls the method on the component just returns immediately with an E_FAIL. The breakpoint in the component (right at the top of the method) is never hit although it breaks fine when called from a windows forms app.

Comment: I put a messagebox function at the top of my com components method. Again this gets displayed when I call it from a windows forms app but from the windows service it never displays. This leads me to believe that the windows service is unable to call the com method. How can I solve this? The only solution seems to change the windows service to a desktop application which seems a bit rubbish.

Comment: I would agree that converting to desktop should not be required for you. I have called COM components from services before, so my guess is there is something about your COM component that is unique. What is that this COM does for you?

Comment: Perhaps it inadvertently requires a message pump?

Comment: If it does then what are my options?

Comment: I've decided to give up and just host in a Windows Forms application. This is not ideal but we were going to need a desktop monitor application anyway. So now it just means that the monitor application will also be hosting the service. Of course this means having to login to the machine for the service to run but this isn't that big a deal for this project. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your service in the LocalSystem account (the default for Windows Services)? Your COM component may need to access resources available in an account that can run it normally...

Try editing your service and specifying your account on the [Log On tab](http://www.CoreTechnologies.com/images/services-log-on-tab.jpg).